# Prove that a complex vector $x$, for which $x^T x$ is zero, is an eigenvector of a symmetric complex matrix implies it has multiple eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume we have a nonzero complex vector $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$ with $x^T x=0$. And there is a complex $n$-th matrix $A$ such that $A^T=A$ and $Ax=\lambda x$ for some complex $\lambda\neq 0$. Prove that $A$ must have multiple eigenvalues $\lambda$.

I tried to transform $x$ to the form $(1,ia_2,ia_3,\ldots)$ using orthogonal matrices, where $a_i$ are real numbers, then solve the equation $Ay=\lambda y+ kx$ for some vector $y$ and some number $k$, but this seems too hard to do...

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A.$ We'll show that $f'(\lambda)=0.$

Cosider that $f'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}f(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\det(t I-A)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}  \begin{vmatrix}
      t-a_{11} & \cdots &\frac{d}{dt}(a_{1i}) & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
      \vdots &  & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
      a_{n1} & \cdots &\frac{d}{dt}(a_{ni}) & \cdots & t-a_{nn} 
  \end{vmatrix}=\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{adj}(tI-A)).$

If $\mathrm{rank}(\lambda I-A)\leq n-2,$ then $f'(\lambda)=0.$

If $\mathrm{rank}(\lambda I-A)= n-1,$ then $\mathrm{rank}\,\mathrm{adj}(\lambda I-A)=1,$ that is, $\mathrm{adj}(\lambda I-A)=\alpha\beta^\ast$ for some nonzero $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{C}^n.$ But $(\lambda I-A)\mathrm{adj}(\lambda I-A)=\mathrm{adj}(\lambda I-A)(\lambda I-A)=0,$ then $\mathrm{adj}(\lambda I-A)=kxx^T$ for nonzero scalar $k,$ which implies $f'(\lambda)=\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{adj}(\lambda I-A))=0.$